# Gatherings during sefira period

Tags: sefirat-ha-omer

Is getting together for a (immediate) family brunch during early sefira period permissible (home or restaurant)?
Nothing is being celebrated. it is just a time when most family members are free to meet.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Daniel!

Comment: Why do you think that a family brunch would be forbidden during the Omer period? By "early sefira period" do you mean Chol Hamoed?

Comment: A 3rd party had requested that I ask.  Actually,  I was just told that it is to celebrate a 60th birthday with a handful of family members at a restaurant..It would take place after Pesach, before Lag Ba'Omer. Thank you.  Good Shabbos/Moed tov